# A case of active voice vs passive voice

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, differences

What’s the difference between the following sentences?

- *There are some apples to pick up.*
- *There are some apples to be picked up.*

Comment: Abbreviating “there are” is very questionable.

Comment: The second is more likely to be said by your mother, with a stern face, when you come in from playing outside.